# How to avoid for & while loops in Pandas in order to optimize the execution time?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, timestamp

Basically I'm using Pandas to manipulate large DataFrames and by now I understood that using loops are forbidden in this library since it's not practical and your code takes forever to execute. The current script is working but in an unprofessional manner since it's executed in 1 min if apply it to my whole dataframe. Since the script is too long, I'm just gonna point out a simple loop from it in order to get a grasp of how I can proceed for the remaining ones.

Let's suppose we have this df called 'chosen_data' that contains start & end dates & duration of available slots in which we can perform a task (I shall provide a sample so you can reproduce it if you wish). Let's fix the task duration to x = 24h, if my first available slot's duration is 100hours I want to subdivide it into 100-24=76 portions where each one's duration is equals to 'x'. I want to store these portions into a new dataframe (called result) containing start & end dates of each subdivision.

**Here is the related portion of code :**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['3/6/1999 5:00','3/8/1999 0:00',43],['3/8/1999 22:00','3/12/1999 19:00',93],['3/12/1999  22:00','3/21/1999 20:00',214],['3/22/1999 19:00','3/26/1999 3:00',80]]
chosen_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Duration [Hours]'])
chosen_data[['Start Date','End Date']] = chosen_data[['Start Date','End Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Start Date','End Date', 'Duration [Hours]'])
x = 24 # Task duration(normaly it's a user input variable)
for i in chosen_data.index : 
    fenetre = chosen_data.copy()
    num_subdiv = fenetre['Duration [Hours]'].loc[i] - x    
    for j in range(int(num_subdiv)) :        
        fenetre['Start Date'].loc[i] = fenetre['Start Date'].loc[i] + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit ='h')
        # fenetre['Start Date'].loc[i] = fenetre['Start Date'].loc[i] + pd.to_timedelta(j, unit ='h')
        fenetre['End Date'].loc[i] = fenetre['Start Date'].loc[i] + pd.to_timedelta(x , unit ='h')
        # fenetre['End Date'].loc[i] = fenetre['End Date'].loc[i] + pd.to_timedelta(j - substract ,   unit ='h')      
        result = result.append(fenetre.loc[i] , ignore_index= True)
        
result['Duration [Hours]'] = (result['End Date'] - result['Start Date']) / pd.to_timedelta(1, unit = 'h')
```

How can I avoid looping for such a simple task ?

- Desired output :

[image]

Comment: Your computation seems a bit complex as for result : EndDate ever changes, and StartDate is just 24h before, and Duration is always 24, is that normal ? 24 be replaced by any `x`

Comment: This portion of code came in the middle of the whole script, maybe I made it seem too complex for nothing. I'm sure if I think outside the box i'll be able to simplify it, that why I posted on this website to get second opinions. As for your question, it's normal that the duration of each 'result' row is 24 ( or x) since i'm subdividing the chosen_data intervals into 24h intervals. However I didn't understand your remark about End Date never changing ... Can you please reformulate ?

Comment: Look my answer. You change StartDate to be 24h before EndDate, so when you change EndDate to be Start+x it never changes as you JUST ALREADY set Start to be End-x

Comment: https://replit.com/@azro352/AdmirableCommonInvocation#main.py You code shows 4 lines only as result

Comment: I guess Stackoverflow changes my syntax a bit. In your code, from line 17 to 19 should be inside the second for-loop. Add tabulations & it's all good

Comment: Was I ambiguous or unclear @azro ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231970/discussion-between-keyser-soze-and-azro).